# Jasmine.js error handling

Tags: jasmine

When there is an Error in Jasmine tests, it just print the stack and hides it, is there a way rethrow it, so it can be debugged from the JavaScript Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty obvious, the Jasmine spec runner has a no try/catch checkbox at the top left